# Bitbake require pyhton3.8

Tags: linux, embedded

After downloading all packages require and cloning poky
I ran the cammand...
Source oe-init-build-env ../build
It says sorry python 3.8 or later is require for this version of bitbake.

So I did alias python=python3.8
And alias python3=python3.8

Now my source oe-init-build-env ../ build command works.

But after that Bitbake core-image-minimal goes into error it says sorry python 3.8 or later is require for this version of bitbake.

I have attached the image below for reference.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZKToz.jpg)

Comment: I have same problem, did you find a solution?